# How to get the list of all QPushButton from a specific tab in Python Pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Python 3.7 Pyqt5 GUI with several tabs.
In the 2nd tab, I have a few QPushButtons. Each name of button has an id number and I need to hide or show some of these buttons depending on this id number.

I can't simply use self.name_of_button.hide() because:
from a side I have a list of ID numbers
from the other side, I have more than 50 buttons.

So I would like to loop all my buttons of my tab N°2 and check if the id in the

```
button name is in ly list of ids:
list_id=[1,2,3,4,5]
for button in QPushbuttons:
    text = button.text() 
    for id in list_id:
        if text.find(str(id))!=-1:
             button.setHidden(True)
```

SO I need to get the list of buttons of these specific Tab.
I know how to hide/show a QPushbuttons. But I don't know how to get the list of the buttons of a specific tab with their names.

I tried this code but it gives only 1 element instead of the list of buttons:

```
# self.tab_run_one_task is my tab N°2
buttons = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_run_one_task)
```

**I am using QT Designer to make the GUI:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 447)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 701, 361))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton3"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton4"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Here is the main code which displays the GUI:**

```
from simpleui2 import Ui_MainWindow


# === The UI ===============================================================================================
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        # I want for example hide the buttons 'PushButton3' and 'PushButton4'
        buttons = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        print(buttons)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()
```

**Output:**

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x000002E15A70F9D8>
```

As you can see the print output display one Button element without the name.

Comment: please provide a [mre], your question is unclear

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc I edited my question with some code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: then use `self.pushButton_3.hide()` and `self.pushButton_4.hide()`

Comment: No I can't because I need to identify by some strings inside the text of button which ones I need to show or hide. I edited the question to add more details of my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by identifier? the names of the variables are not identifiers (your question is still confusing), for example `x = Foo()`  `y = x`, what is the identifier of the object of class Foo: x or y?

Comment: mmm, maybe: `for i in list_id:` `button = getattr(self, "pushButton_{}".format(i))` `button.hide()`